# How to select version of library to use in OSGI bundle

Tags: java, osgi, jira-plugin, jakarta-mail

I develop jira plugin, where I should send email with images.
There is one bug with javax.mail-1.4.5, that was fixed in javax.mail-1.4.7
I tried a lot, but was not able when plugin deployed on jira tell to use my version of javax.mail (1.4.7). It all the time use javax.mail-1.4.5 from root class loader.
I all the time recieve next Exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method "javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getDataHandler()Ljavax/activation/DataHandler;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage, and its superclass loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader), have different Class objects for the type getDataHandler used in the signature
    at com.solarwinds.MailSenderJob.buildSimpleMessage(MailSenderJob.java:163)
```

My question is next: how to tell OSGi, that here I would like to use another version of library?

Comment: So you installed javax.mail jar into the embedded OSGi container of Jira?

Comment: I tried to use jira's embeded javax.mail, also in my pom.xml I selected desired version of javax.mail. Seems like no changes were made and javax.mail from root classloader still worked in my plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Add the specific library to the class path of your project. Or if you're using Maven, simply edit the pom.xml file.

Comment: This will make the library available at compile time but not necessarily use the correct library in the OSGi runtime.